# running an app built with .net3.5 on a machine witch .net 3.5 and 4.0 both are installed

Tags: .net, browser, version

We have written an app built with .NET 3.5 and when we run it on a machine that .NET 4.5 has been installed on , WPF forms behavior changes on IE browser and this cause some problems, when I remove .NET 4 from machine and still there is a .net 3.5 version, problem solved. how can I have .NET 4 or later installed on my machine and force my app work as when it had just .net3.5 installed.
I have added this section to my app config and it doesn't solve my problem

```
 <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
```

I found that although have built my app with .net3.5,running in browser presentationhost loads .net4 assemblies in runtime. but I don't know why!and how to make it load .net3.5 assemblies.

dependency section in the application manifest is

```
     <dependency>
                   <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite"  allowDelayedBinding="true">
                   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime"   version="2.0.50727.0" />
                   </dependentAssembly>  
             </dependency>
```

but if client system has .net4 assemblies installed on, .net4 assemplies will be loaded in runtime!

Comment: Lower version framework will not work on higher version framework

Comment: @parvezalamkhan I changed manifest files manually and it worked :) my app worked with .net3.5 on client machines which had installed higher versions of .net frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem adding bellow lines to my application manifest. this forces presentation host to use the exact 3.5 version of core dlls

```
 <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime" version="2.0.50727.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" version="3.5.0.0" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="WindowsBase" version="3.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```